# Usage with "in this"

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

I am writing a technical report. I want to link previous sentence with the current sentence, giving the reasons.

I used the following wording:

> In this end, this report discuses a novel approach...

Also, suppose I am describing something and then I want to explain more about that particular case by my next sentence. For that, I used the following:

> In this case, a segment must have a single relationship...

When writing I am having many occasions like the above two. So, can I have synonyms for "In this end" and "In this case"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with the "*In this case,*" transition. However, I think the "*In this end,*" transition is probably incorrect and should be *To this end,*. E.g., *We want our business to double by 2015. **To this end,** we have decided to triple our R & D budget and hire 50 new researchers.* Does this look reasonable to you?

Comment: thanks...i got. but i am looking some synonym to say "In this case" also because always i cant use the same phrase. i was looking for synonyms for both phrases... thanks again

Comment: For _To this end,_", you might try **To {accomplish / do / achieve} this,** or, perhaps, **{For / Because of} this,**.

Comment: thanks... any synonyms for the "in this case" is also welcome to know

Comment: For "_In this case,_", you might try "_In this {instance / event / context / circumstance / situation},_". Much depends upon context.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are a non-native speaker, because a native speaker would not write *In this end*. What you need is *To this end*, which means 'for this purpose'. *In this case* is fine, but it doesn't mean the same as *To this end*. You can sometimes use *here* as an alternative, but it depends on the context.

Comment: thanks...i am not native speaker.. instead of writing "in this case" what can I say... looking for some other similar phrases as well.

Comment: _In this case_ can be used in many contexts, and I can't think of any alternative, apart from _here_, or perhaps _In this example_, that can be used so widely. You might have to be more specific and write something like _In this experiment_ or _In this approach_.